# Retrieve foreign key values in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have 2 tables

1. User
2. Access

In the user table I have 4 columns in total but 1 in foreign key of another table (Access).

1. UserId
2. UserName
3. UserEmail
4. AccessId(FK)

And in the Access table I have 2 columns

1. AccessId
2. Yes/NO

I'm able to retrieve the UserId but not AccessId because it is a foreign key in User table.

Here is the code I have written

```
var test = (from userName in User
            select userName.AccessId).ToList();
```

This is the result I get

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1

I want to get the AccessId as well, can you help me please?

Comment: `(from userName in User select userName.AccessId).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: it's unclear to me what you're wanting to accomplish and what the exact error or issue you're having. please provide more context.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius here is the result I'm getting
System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[Access]

Comment: are you trying to convert it to string?

Comment: `(from userName in User select userName.AccessId).FirstOrDefault().AccessId` then. I'm guessing your entity properties here since you haven't posted any.

Comment: @Aominè I want to retrieve the AccessId from the table called User.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I have tried your query but It does not suggest me AccessId

Comment: Why not  in the Dbml, create the association between those 2 table. this way you can easly acess to any property of Access.

Comment: post your entity classes then.

Comment: @arekzyla I have tried to convert it to string as well but same result 
System.Data.Linq.EntitySet`1[Keuring.Business.Klant]

Comment: User.Select(user => user.AccessId).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 2):

Well

```
var test = (from userName in User
            select userName.AccessId).ToList();
```

Returns a list, so that is what you get. A list of AccessID's.

If you need the ID;s

```
foreach (var aSingleAccessID in test)
{
// do something with each accessID
}
```